# When I deploy my R shiny app to shinyapps.io, I get 'Error: oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment'. How can I fix this?

Tags: r, shiny

The app is designed to scrap twitter for word frequencies for a given search term, and then create a word cloud based on the frequencies. It works when I run it on my local machine. The following is the source code:

```
library(shiny)

library(twitteR)

library(wordcloud)

library(tm)

twitter_key<-"XXX"

twitter_secret<-"XXX"

oauth<-setup_twitter_oauth(twitter_key, twitter_secret)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Twitter Wordcloud"),

textInput("text", label = h3("Search term:"), value = "president"),

actionButton("goButton", "Search"),

hr(),

mainPanel(

plotOutput("distPlot")

)

))

server = function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

input$goButton

isolate({

mach_tweets = searchTwitter(input$text, n=200, lang="en")

mach_text = sapply(mach_tweets, function(x) x$getText())

mach_text = sapply(mach_text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII",          sub=""))

mach_text = gsub(" https.*","",mach_text)

mach_corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(mach_text))

tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(mach_corpus,

control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,

stopwords = c(input$text, stopwords("english")),

removeNumbers = TRUE, tolower = TRUE))

m = as.matrix(tdm)

word_freqs = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE)

dm = data.frame(word=names(word_freqs), freq=word_freqs)

wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, random.order=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))

})

})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

Run the next line of code in the Console, but first make sure that the .httr-oauth file that `setup_twitter_oauth`creates is in the same directory that ui.R and server.R are.

```
    rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = getwd(),appFiles = NULL)
```

What it does is that its deploy all files in the working Directory, including the .httr-oauth file that is the key here.